# X12 004060 error “REF*3J*0000 Segment was not found.”

Tags: edi

I purchased, downloaded and installed the version 004050 translation matrices. I was told that version 004060 was essentially the same as the 004050 version and to simply update any references to 004050 to 004060 in all the document classes. Which I did.
However when I tried to deserialize an EDI document I got the error "Segment was not found" on the line REF*3J*0000.
Any ideas on what I can try?

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of elements was out of order for the 850 document type. The S_CUR (Order=2), G_SAC (Order=3), S_DTM (Order=4) and S_REF(Order=5) needed to go in that order.
  Once I changed the ordering in the EF_X12_004050_850.cs file (I did not rename the file, just the internal namespace to the 004060 version), EdiFabric was able to import the data.